# Calling Innovator Contest 2011-Use of NokiaQtSDK for Developing VOIP and APS Apps

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, s60

I want to develop application for the Calling innovator contest 2011. It seems the application developed using 4.6.3 (NokiaQtSDK) are accepted.

I have some questions that needs some help

1. Can we develop application that uses VOIP and APS Plugins ?
2. Is it acceptable for the contest , since these plug ins are more platform specific ?
3. Can we ignore the built in Nokiaqtsdk and use the 4.6.3 sources with S60 to develop this app ?
4. Does Calling Innovator Contest 2011 have a separate forum for discussion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it what stops you from reading competition's rules. Once you do that, adopt the simple rule: whatever is not expressly prohibited is to be considered allowed. Yes, you can use all the platform specific APIs you want and you can develop it with any SDK as long as you know what you are doing and you get a working application to submit to the Ovi Store. Just make sure that the most of it is made with Qt, since that is indeed a requirement.